# "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop " for object containing "key" attribute in array

Tags: reactjs

The component `MyComp` takes an array of objects from which it will construct Buttons. I also provide a `key` for each object. In this case, 1 Button should be created from a 1-element object array:

```
<MyComp 
    buttons={[{"key":"approvalsButton","variant":"info","text":"Approvals Queue","url":"/approvals"}]} />
```

Component Definition

```
export default function MyComp(props) {
    return (

        <Col lg={6} className="home-tile">
            <div className="home-tile-content">
                <div className="home-tile-buttons">                 
                    {
                        /* Loop through specified Buttons (if any) and their object attributes */
                    
                        props.buttons 
                        ?                   
                            props.buttons.map(button => (
                                <LinkContainer to={button.url}>
                                    <Button key={button.key} variant={button.variant}>{button.text}</Button>
                                </LinkContainer>
                            ))
                        :
                            ''  
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </Col>
```

But I'm still getting

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MyComp`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, the elements being rendered by `map` need a `key` property to uniquely identify them.  This has nothing to do with the *objects* you're using or whether or not *they* have a property called `key`, this just refers to the actual component being rendered.  In this case the `<LinkContainer>`.

In most cases you won't need to use this property, but the framework does.  So in most cases you can simply use the second argument to the `map` callback which is the index of the collection.  For example:

```
props.buttons.map((button, i) => (
  <LinkContainer key={i} to={button.url}>
    <Button variant={button.variant}>{button.text}</Button>
  </LinkContainer>
))
```

If the objects in your array do have a unique property then you can also use that just as easily:

```
props.buttons.map(button => (
  <LinkContainer key={button.key} to={button.url}>
    <Button variant={button.variant}>{button.text}</Button>
  </LinkContainer>
))
```

Comment: Thanks, but why didn't the `key` on the `Button` (e.g. `<Button key={button.key}` work, as I show in my OP? I tried that as well, and it failed.

Comment: @geneb.: Because that's on the `<Button>` component, but `map` is returning the `<LinkContainer>` component.